# Stringing two adjectives in one sentence

Tags: grammar

I have the sentence: "I am not interested **in** **answering** this question"

and the sentence: "I am not able **to** **answer** this question"

And I want to make them into one sentence. As you will see, I am struggling.

1. "I am not interested, nor able to answer this question"
2. "I am not interested, nor able answering this question"
3. "I am not interested in, nor able to, answer this question"
4. "I am not interested in, nor am I able to answer this question"

and so on.

What's the correct form?

Comment: Sometimes it's better to just spell it out:  "I am not interested in answering this question, nor am I able to answer it."

Comment: (1) is grammatical but doesn't explicitly say you're not interested in the question. (2) is not grammatical. (4) has a redundant second occurrence of "am", but is fine. (3) is also fine and exhibits parellelism on "interested in" and "able to", but you need to fix your commas: "I am not interested in, nor able to answer, this question."

Comment: You can also change "not" to "neither": "I am neither interested in nor able to answer this question."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to just spell it out: "I am not interested in answering this question, nor am I able to answer it."

(But I'm answering it anyway, so there will be a valid answer to satisfy Community.)

Answer (score -1):

The third option seems best to me. The first is also acceptable. The second, with the gerund inserted, would need to be recast.